# Restoring from backup files on the principle server in a synchronous mirroring environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring

I have a synchronous mirroring environment with automatic fail-over using sql server 2008 standard editions.

I want to restore a mirrored database on principle to specific point of time using full and transaction log backups. For this, do I need to turn off the mirroring session, then restore the database to a point of time on principle using backups and then start a fresh mirroring session or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Since you have to start from a full backup, you must break the mirror and re-establish it again once you rolled back in time your principal database. Of course, all applications using the database will be offline during this.